# Started failed Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I start Android Studio I see the following:

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't create Engine
at com.google.android.filament.Engine.create(Engine.java:46)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin.viewer.Filamentor$3.run(Filamentor.java:103)
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: try to uninstall and reinstall again

Comment: It looks like you have a corrupted installation file - completely uninstall Android Studio and download it again from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have folders .cache and .local owned by your user (not root).

To change owner you need to run this:

```
sudo chown -R your_user_name:your_user_group .cache
sudo chown -R your_user_name:your_user_group .local
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download the Application from the official android studio website. Install it again and give you laptop full access to the internet because apart from the Studio software it downloads many other plugins and sdk tools etc, so install it again giving it full access to the internet. I hope it helps.